# How to compose new type from Array<keyof T>?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I need some help with typescript generic typing. My aim is to do something like the one as follows. The function in the end should use first parameter index name to create new type **Record<Key, Attributes[Key]>** but the keys should be Picked from the array of keys.

[Link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgEwgDwMIHsA2BXAtnAZwB4AoKWKFYCRAqA4AJwEs4BzAGjKgEFgm6VGgjoAlCAGN0jBEQYt2HKAEM4IAHwl1UALxRxUmURhKejRspBEA1hBDoAZr36MC69QG4SJUJCiplRngkZAg6PQByACMLRAB9XHQkTAioAB8oaNiEOIllajZpEAivElZqRgdlCWgYANcoAG9uchjVBAAuTIJrJOVUjIiHaQQBzIA3LEmSlqg8gqKuoeVcZkxi9MzHBwBaRnRlUc2IiwlWNhnyckTkrvlzrwBfbylCYDnA4JQMHHwCLq+aCweEIRHqgLCSjqgTcuiasza8XmEEKjBAXQA2ll2hElBFkajigBdLhXKCInI3CCYTHYxC4zJUlIkkjPEgAenZUAAYqwEB9GOSQOTsuymVAdnNpIxJMASK8GFAZQBHbDMGUIeoARjhDj59QAQiBAQAKbjNMl8lBLCkJJLUhmcqDAAAWzDo6Dg0HdlGUBBA3EepPhZIpSx6fVxsyZS3QEmAynGzH6weeAEpSk7eYgBUKRe12QSihKoKxDDL4-LPYqVWqNfUAEy6-WBI2m82zK3IG3ZXL5FFFKPkIPmqBO10+n24YUSF3KTCYGhsCAI7JLYYyIdXItopanc5b672mmMz1IdCOrll6WyksEF3obCYflwdDvKLQF0QGVKV-vTDutQ-KsPmSL9oStIUgy+LgYOLLDiQGbeFmfK5lEwoUoWsFoiW17mLKVZvEqECquqECaoETZ6HqiCGsaiAoGa5AWlcXY9u0drJFuI7MWOV5wOWt6SqsBAEOcp5cVAADubqzqWdAAQw5GlnAoGUsekHZNBTIRPBVxhpkG6jKmiEeEAA)

**Full code**:

```js
type IndexColumns<
  I extends string,
  Attrs extends Record<string, any>
> = Record<I, Array<keyof Attrs>>;

type CarIndexes = 'brand_model' | 'brand_category';

interface ICars {
    brand: 'skoda' | 'ford' | 'volvo';
    category: 'family' | 'off-road' | 'racing';
    model: string;
}

const carIndexColumns: IndexColumns<CarIndexes, ICars> = {
    brand_category: ['brand', 'category'],
    brand_model: ['brand', 'model'],
}

// Find car by brand/model - correct
const requiredCar1 = findCarByIndex(
  {
    index: 'brand_model', // this one is easy
  },
  {
    brand: 'skoda',
    model: 'octavia',
  }
);

// Find car by brand/category - incorrect
const requiredCar2 = findCarByIndex(
  {
    index: 'brand_category',
  },
  { // this is my challenge
    brand: 'ford',
    category: 'racing',
    model: 'mondeo', // incorrect - should not be here, not listed in brand_category: ['brand', 'category'],
  }
);

// Find car by brand/category - incorrect
const requiredCar2 = findCarByIndex(
  {
    index: 'brand_model',
  },
  { // incorrect - missing 'model' which is listed in brand_model: ['brand', 'model'],
    brand: 'ford',
  }
);
```

I've spent a lot of time in testing reading. Even ChatGPT is not successful and it looks like a simple task to me.

Anybody here to give me a helping hand?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what findCarByIndex is supposed to do. Are you asking how to get the right type for the 2nd parameter?

Comment: the findCarByIndex is just a placeholder. I only need the typing of the params. 1st param should include the name of the index and the 2nd type should provide list of columns defined in array of the carIndexColumns[index-name]

Comment: included invalid parameters to show how it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first change I would make is to use `satisfies` instead of a type assertion, so you don't lose the type information there:

```
const carIndexColumns = {
    brand_category: ["brand", "category"],
    brand_model: ["brand", "model"],
} satisfies IndexColumns<CarIndexes, ICars>;
```

Then you could write `findCarByIndex` as follows:

```
declare function findCarByIndex<Index extends CarIndexes>(
    filter: { index: Index },
    arg: { [K in (typeof carIndexColumns)[Index][number]]: ICars[K] },
): void; /* or whatever return type */
```

We can "store" the given index and then look up the properties with it. Finally, we map the properties to the correct type from `ICars`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ADz2QS8cjyKtkTA65f2PcDDHvR9n2fXBhxEStMEwShmAgUTAI6ZYRgkQSAM+RYIWWM4Li0gDIKJKUkHQO9uyYIjRA+ScCHLdBsEwBAoDgdAPhjKBy1jCB2Hcj5MCpChXKYbCQX4pYXQAckxaL2GivCIWi0khPTVDu3Q1z8joQdh0xXDIohAjrOnWzSPeRdKPXBoAGYGL3IIWMPP8VI9K0sivYkjLTVrtPzKyxTK8UCLWAgCAuKBouJaKyyfWSLWoILaGoj1wqxG9cRiuKEpm1LtMxdTRh65DvCAA)

Comment: Not at the pc anymore but I’ll definitely look at it. Thank you